# What sorts of recommendation questions are on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I figure we should start talking now about the types of questions that we know will come up sooner or later.  So let's start with recommendations.

There are two types of recommendation questions I foresee:

1. Asking which type of tool to use:

   - Which is better to take, a hatchet or folding saw?
   - What's the best tool to use for x?
2. Those asking for feature comparisons within a tool category (there may be overlap with the previous):

   - One two-person tent or two one-persons?
   - Real cam or tri-cam?
3. Those asking for comparisons between brands

   - Which brand of knife is best / should I buy?

Recall that we need to avoid "list" questions, and those without a correct answer.  From that point of view, I think most questions in category 1 and 2 can be on-topic, but most of 3 shouldn't be.

What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with the breakdown. I just might ask a question on one vs two person tents! :) Asking about brands is a different matter. This is not a review site and products change often.

Answer (score 10):

It seems to me it will be difficult to avoid questions with no correct answer, since unlike programming, much of what works in the Great Outdoors is a matter of personal opinion. So you can get 20 recommendations, and they all be right.

So much of outdoor skill and survival also comes from improvising - which although might not provide the best solution, it can provide a solution... is that answer wrong?